# Fast Non-uniform DFT in R

Tags: r, fourier-transform

So, if I want to compute discrete Fourier transform (DFT) in R, I can create my own functions like so:

```
my.dft <- function(x, k) {
  N <- length(x)
  xN <- 0:(N-1)
  out <- sum(x*exp(1i*-2*pi*k*xN/N))
  return(out)
}

vec.dft <- function(x) {
  k <- 0:(length(x) - 1)
  out <- vapply(k,
                function(kn) my.dft(x, kn),
                1i)
  return(out)
}

x <- c(1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6, 3, 6, 5, 4, 6, 4, 7, 3, 2, 6)
vec.dft(x)
```

However I know directly computing DFT like this is inefficient, so there is an implementation of FFT in `stats` package:

```
stats::fft(x)
```

which gets the same result.
The problem I'm having is generalization to the non-uniform DFT, which can be implemented using custom function like this:

```
my.nudft <- function(x,
                     k,
                     p = (0:(length(x) - 1)) / length(x)) {
  out <- sum(x*exp(1i*-2*pi*k*p))
  return(out)
}
```

where `k` is the non-integer frequency computed and `p` is the vector representing the non-uniform position of the data `x`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_discrete_Fourier_transform

Now, the question is, is there some sort of NUFFT implemented already in some package? As far as I can tell, `stats::fft` uses some C port of old Fortran code and doesn't support that. There's a C `fftw` library, which might be used in some packages, but that one doesn't seem to support non-uniform generalization.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question elsewhere? I'm curious as I have the same question.

Comment: No, I ended up using the slow full version programmed using the equations and definition. It turned out that while slow, it was fast enough for me. I didn't find any usable fast NUFFT implementations.